# Apply a LowPassFilter for a period of time, then fade it back to normal?

Tags: c#, audio, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to achieve the very common effect you often have in FPS games when you are hit by a grenade.. When you are hit, a LP Filter kicks in at a low frequency, wait for a couple of seconds before fading it back to normal.
How is this effect created? I'm using C# and Unity 5.
I've tried to google it, but there seems to be very little information about this subject.

My code so far isn't super sexy, I've deleted about everything 250 times in a row now and I'm starting to lose my patience with myself :P

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DamageHandler : MonoBehaviour {

[Range(5000, 22000)] public int standardLpFreq = 22000;
[Range(10, 500)] public int hitLpFreq = 280;

public float timeToHaveEffect = 4f;

private AudioLowPassFilter lpFilter;

void Awake() {
    lpFilter = Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioLowPassFilter> ();

    if (!lpFilter) {
        Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioLowPassFilter>();
        lpFilter = Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioLowPassFilter>();
    }

    InitLPFilter ();
}

private void InitLPFilter() {
    lpFilter.cutoffFrequency = standardLpFreq;
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fading back to normal"? Do you mean the cutoff frequency should sweep back up to 22000?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.. Just setting it back to its "normal state" instantly sound too weird.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the LPF cut off frequency in a coroutine:
http://docs.unity3d.com/500/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html

```
public int standardLpFreq = 22000;
public int hitLpFreq = 280;
public float timeToHaveEffect = 4f;
public float damageBeginTime = 0f;

void HandleHit() {
    lpFilter.cutoffFrequency = hitLpFreq;
    damageBeginTime = Time.time;
    StartCoroutine("DamageSoundEffect");
}

IEnumerator DamageSoundEffect() {

    // Wait...
    while (Time.time - damageBeginTime < timeToHaveEffect) {
        yield return null;
    }

    // Restore normal sound
    lpFilter.cutoffFrequency = standardLpFreq;
}
```

}

If you need softer sweep, update the cut off inside the loop. You can use Mathf.Lerp to compute an intermediate cutoff frequency.

Comment: Thank you.. I'm not used to Mathf.Lerp at all actually, but isn't it only possible to lerp between 0.0 and 1.0?